# Remove all old flow versions using SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, continuous-integration

We have an old field referenced in older flow versions.
We want to remove all older versions using SFDX and only upload the newest version without the field.
Is it possible to do this without manually deleting older flow versions ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have the full details currently. You could probably use the FlowDefinitionView to find the ActiveVersionId \([301](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#301)\) for each FlowDefinitionView.DurableId \([300](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#300)\). Then query FlowVersionView for anything else that references the same FlowDefinitionViewId. That would indicate the older inactive versions that could be deleted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We had the same issue in our project.
we created a script to delete all obsolete flow before/after deployment.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id FROM Flow WHERE Status = 'Obsolete'" --target-org $USERNAME --use-tooling-api --result-format csv > flowTodelete.csv

while read c; do
    if [[ "$c" != "Id" && "$c" != "Your query returned no results." ]]
        then
            sfdx force:data:record:delete --sobject Flow --record-id $c --target-org $USERNAME --use-tooling-api
    fi
done < flowTodelete.csv

rm flowTodelete.csv
```

Comment: Hello Milan,
does this work for you? I always get the following error:
ERROR running force:data:record:delete:  unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 3001w0000000iziAAA
And this record is a FlowDefinition. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi joern, Yes this works quite well in my org.

Comment: It is working well for me today - very useful!  Followed some basic tutorials re writing a shell script and making it executable, and I hard coded my username in the script as i did not have a default username set in sfdx

Comment: one note, I had to change the query from Status = 'Obsolete' to Status != 'Active' as i had a bunch of flows with status of Draft and InvalidDraft after the initial purge.

Comment: to exclude flows in managed packages, add and Definition.NamespacePrefix = '' to the query

Answer (score 6):

From my tests in api version 46 (Summer'19), it seems the procedure described [here](https://www.sfdccloudninja.com/flow/deleting-lots-of-old-flows-process-builders/) still works despite sfdx handling flows differently since api version 43.

1. Find the version numbers of the flow you want to delete by querying FlowDefinitionView
2. pack them all into your destructiveChanges.xml which will look something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
         <types>
           <members>Process_To_Delete-2</members>
           <members>Process_To_Delete-1</members>
           <name>Flow</name>
         </types>
         <version>46.0</version>
       </Package>
   ```
3. use the `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d packageLocation` to deploy the deletion
4. deploy the version of the flow you want to keep

**Note**:
The new way of handling flows since api version 43 means you should technically just put `<members>Process_To_Delete</members>` but this will systematically give you a `insufficient access rights on cross-reference id` as will the `sfdx force:source:delete` command.

**Edit**
So far, it doesn't seem possible to do this with an sfdx command, since only the metadata api allows deleting flow versions.

Comment: This works with SFDX per above and should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sfdx-hardis](https://github.com/hardisgroupcom/sfdx-hardis) plugin to purge flows.
It is also possible to connect to the org via JWT if you want to integrate such process within your CI pipelines

**sfdx hardis:org:purge:flow --name NAMEOFYOURFLOW**

Example:

```
$ sfdx hardis:org:purge:flow --name TestFlow
[sfdx-hardis] You must be connected to an org to perform this command. Please login in the open web browser
Successfully authorized nicolas.vuillamy@gmail.com with org ID 00D09000007FRNzEAO
You may now close the browser
[sfdx-hardis] Successfully logged to https://login.salesforce.com with username nicolas.vuillamy@gmail.com
[sfdx-hardis] Found 2 records:
ID                 MASTERLABEL VERSIONNUMBER DESCRIPTION  STATUS  
30109000000kX8GAAU TestFlow    8             test flowwww Obsolete
30109000000kY2JAAU TestFlow    10            test flowwww Obsolete
[sfdx-hardis] Are you sure you want to delete this list of records in nicolas.vuillamy@gmail.com (y/n)?: y
Successfully deleted record: 30109000000kX8GAAU.
Successfully deleted record: 30109000000kY2JAAU.
[sfdx-hardis] Deleted the following list of records:
ID                 MASTERLABEL VERSIONNUMBER DESCRIPTION  STATUS
30109000000kX8GAAU TestFlow    8             test flowwww Obsolete
30109000000kY2JAAU TestFlow    10            test flowwww Obsolete
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all inactive flows using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script to delete all obsolete flow versions from specified org
#The format: deleteInactiveFlows.sh <your_org_alias or username>

FILE="flowsToDelete.csv"
USERNAME="$1"

QUERY="SELECT Id, Definition.DeveloperName, VersionNumber \
FROM Flow \
WHERE Status = 'Obsolete' \
ORDER BY Definition.DeveloperName, VersionNumber"

RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
YELLOW="\e[33m"
RESET="\e[0m"

function query_flow_versions {
    #Query flow versions from specified org using tooling api, add rows to csv file
    sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "${QUERY}" --targetusername "${USERNAME}" --usetoolingapi --resultformat csv > "${FILE}"
}

function delete_flow_versions {
    deleted=0
    while read -r flow;
    do
      #Delete flow version by id (cannot use bulk with tooling api enabled)
      IFS=',' read -ra properties <<< "$flow"
        echo "Processing flow ${properties[1]}, version ${properties[2]}"
        result=$(sfdx force:data:record:delete --sobjecttype Flow --sobjectid ${properties[0]} --targetusername "${USERNAME}" --usetoolingapi) || true
        if [[ "${result}" == "Successfully deleted record"* ]]
        then
            deleted=$((deleted+1))
        fi
    done <"${FILE}"

    echo -e "${GREEN}Deleted flow versions: ${deleted}${RESET}"
}

if [ -z "${USERNAME}" ];
then
    echo -e "${RED}Username should be provided as a parameter${RESET}"
else
    query_flow_versions

    if [ -s "${FILE}" ]
    then
        sed -i -e '1d' ${FILE}

        if [ -s "${FILE}" ]
        then
            queried=$(wc -l < "${FILE}")
            echo -e "${YELLOW}Inactive flow versions queried: ${queried}${RESET}"
            delete_flow_versions
        else
            echo -e "${GREEN}No flow versions to delete${RESET}"
        fi
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Some error occurred during retrieving flow versions${RESET}"
fi

    rm "${FILE}"
fi

read -r -p $'\n'"Window can be closed"
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can do it this way to get a members list to remove, so you can copy and paste into your destructive changes file. Basically, it queries the the flows to remove and uses a custom expression to join flow API name and the version number.

```
$username = "<your alias or username>"
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, Definition.DeveloperName, VersionNumber FROM Flow WHERE Status = 'Obsolete'" -u $username -t --json |
 ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty result | Select-Object -ExpandProperty records |
 Select-Object -Property @{n="Members";e={"<members>$($_.Definition.DeveloperName)-$($_.VersionNumber)</members>"}} | Sort-Object Members | Out-Host
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an inactive version of flow, then you have to first of all remove all the Paused And Failed Flow Interviews, then only you will be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same situation and used the query below with 'Tooling API' to extract all obsolete flow versions.
Please Note: I have used Data export option on the Salesforce Inspector browser extension

```
select id, masterlabel  from Flow where status='Obsolete' and processType = 'Flow' order by masterlabel
```

filter the records you want to delete on Excel or any spreadsheet app,
Use the Data import option on Salesforce Inspector.
Select Delete, and Use Tooling API.
copy the filtered spreadsheet content and Delete.