# Mass Delete flow and flow versions

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, workbench

I'm trying to delete some old flow which are inactive via workbench.

**DestructiveChanges.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Advanced_Round_Robin</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>Ï
</Package>
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">    
  <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

I've added both file in zip and in workbench when I deploy using this zip file I get below error.

> insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

[image]

What permission I need to have to perform this action?

Also is there way I can delete few version of same flow only? Like keep only last 3-4 version and delete all previous version of given flow?

Thank you.

Comment: see https://docs.copado.com/article/8l069zes9f-destructive-changes-in-copado-doesn-t-support-flow-and-process-builder for an example

Comment: @cropredy so I need to mention version of flows that I want to delete?

Comment: YEP -- versions of flows

Comment: Just use sfdx hardis:org:purge:flow :) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/332933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have experienced this issue in the past. According to this [release doc](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fullname.htm), version numbers of the flow are omitted in API 44.0+. However when you try to do a destructive change deployment to delete a version of the flow using API 44.0 or higher it lets you delete ONLY if the version number is appended to the flow name.

For example -- If your destructive changes look like below, with hyphenated version number, it will be deleted

```
<types>

  <members>FlowName-4</members>

  <name>Flow</name>

 </types>
```

The Salesforce product team has confirmed this as expected behavior. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) says “To deploy or retrieve a version, you can specify the version number. For example, sample flow-3 specifies version 3 of the flow whose unique name is sample flow. If you don’t specify a version number, the flow is the latest version.”

Answer (score 10):

Mass delete flow version is also possible via `Tooling API`
(using [Salesforce inspector chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) or another tool of your choice)

1. Export flow version records by querying on `FlowVersionView`

```
SELECT DurableId, FlowDefinitionView.ApiName, VersionNumber, Status 
from FlowVersionView 
where  FlowDefinitionView.ApiName='YOUR_FLOW_API_NAME'
```

2. If you are using Salesforce inspector chrome extension, go to Data Import **Enable Tooling API**
3. Then choose DELETE action on `Flow` object by matching `Id` with `DurableId` column in exported results

**Note**:

> You can delete a flow version as long as it isn’t active and has no paused interviews. If the flow version has paused interviews, wait for
> those interviews to resume and finish, or delete them.

[More info](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flow.htm)

Comment: I had did extension, but didn't realize how powerful it was. Thanks so much; my clicking finger appreciates it ;)

Comment: @CharlesNaccio thanks. yes the plugin is a life saver sometimes, good to know this answer helped u