# GitHub Actions: Delete obsolete salesforce lightning flow version using Shell script and YAML

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, github-actions, powershell

Before validating and deploying the components, I am attempting to remove any outdated versions of a flow. I discovered a solution on the Salesforce Stack Exchange.
[image]

[Remove all old flow versions using SFDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275679/remove-all-old-flow-versions-using-sfdx)

I have made some adjustments to the code based on my requirements. The code has been corrected as follows:

```
#!C:\tools\git\bin\bash.exe

#Script to delete all obsolete flow versions from specified org
#The format: deleteInactiveFlows.sh

echo "Invoking Shell Script"

FILE="flowsToDelete.csv"
USERNAME=$SANDBOX_USERNAME

QUERY="SELECT Id, Definition.DeveloperName, VersionNumber \
FROM Flow \
WHERE Status = 'Obsolete' \
ORDER BY Definition.DeveloperName, VersionNumber"

echo $QUERY
echo $FILE
echo $USERNAME

RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
YELLOW="\e[33m"
RESET="\e[0m"

function query_flow_versions {
    echo "Inside query_flow_versions"
    #Query flow versions from specified org using tooling api, add rows to csv file
    sf data query --query "${QUERY}" --target-org "${USERNAME}" --use-tooling-api --result-format csv > "${FILE}"
}

function delete_flow_versions {
    deleted=0
    while read -r flow;
    do
      #Delete flow version by id (cannot use bulk with tooling api enabled)
      IFS=',' read -ra properties <<< "$flow"
        echo "Processing flow ${properties[1]}, version ${properties[2]}"
        result=$(sf data delete record --sobjecttype Flow --sobjectid ${properties[0]} --target-org "${USERNAME}" --use-tooling-api) || true
        if [[ "${result}" == "Successfully deleted record"* ]]
        then
            deleted=$((deleted+1))
        fi
    done <"${FILE}"

    echo -e "${GREEN}Deleted flow versions: ${deleted}${RESET}"
}

if [ -z $SANDBOX_USERNAME ];
then
    echo -e "${RED}Username should be provided as a parameter${RESET}"
else
    query_flow_versions

    if [ -s "${FILE}" ]
    then
        sed -i -e '1d' ${FILE}

        if [ -s "${FILE}" ]
        then
            queried=$(wc -l < "${FILE}")
            echo -e "${YELLOW}Inactive flow versions queried: ${queried}${RESET}"
            delete_flow_versions
        else
            echo -e "${GREEN}No flow versions to delete${RESET}"
        fi
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Some error occurred during retrieving flow versions${RESET}"
fi

    rm "${FILE}"
fi
```

From YAML, I am passing the Sandbox username:

```
# Delete Obsolete flows in the sandbox
 - name: Delete Obsolete flows in the sandbox
    env:
   SANDBOX_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DEVSANDBOX_SFDX_USERNAME }}
   run: sh .github/build/deleteInactiveFlows.sh
```

Facing this issue after running this script :
[image]

Not able to understand what this issue is ".github/build/deleteInactiveFlows.sh: 29: Syntax error: "}" unexpected"